# IE8 overlaps inline-block elements in a floated div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a web page with three radio buttons with a label in `span` elements which are styled as `display: inline-block`, all of them in a `div` styled with `float: right`. This renders fine in all browsers except IE8 (of course).

Expected (chrome version):

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Result in IE8:

[image: IE8 screenshot]

The shortest code I could come up with to reproduce is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>           
 <title>Home Page</title> 
 <style>
  div {
    //The issue remains whatever the value of float
    //but disappears if I remove this line
    float: right;
  }
  span {
    //The issue disappears if I remove this line or use any other value
    display: inline-block;
  }
 </style>
</head> 
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Labello 1</span>
    <span>Long Label 2</span>
    <span>Labellebleue 3</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This can undoubtedly be called a bug, but is there an "explanation" of it somehow? E.g. I have heard of the "hasLayout" model of IE, but have yet to grasp the concept completely.

Is there a cross-browser way of achieving the same effect? The reason I am using `inline-block` is to use margin and padding on the elements. It's OK if it does not work with IE<=7.

On this simplistic example, the issue remains if I replace `span` elements with `div` elements with the same styling, but disappears if I use `div` elements with `float: left`. Is that the proper solution? Before applying this across all my real (fairly big) pages, is there anything I should know before applying this solution (basically, differences between left-floated `div`s and inline-block `span`s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't find a way to have `inline-block` behave as expected, I finally resorted to float the `span`. Something of this sort:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>           
 <title>Home Page</title> 
 <style>
  div {
    float: right;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
 </style>
</head> 
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Labello 1</span>
    <span>Long Label 2</span>
    <span>Labellebleue 3</span>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works both in my simplistic example and in my particular use case.

But I am still interested in finding out why my original example does not work, even when applying the "cross-browser inline-block" suggested by Chankey!

Answer (score 2):

Use the below to get cross-browser `display:inline-block`:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

Also read: [Cross Browser Support for inline-block Styling](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)

Comment: Thanks, great link! Will try. When did Fiferox start supporting inline-block? Will it affect many users if I don't use the -moz hack?

Comment: What is your targeted audience? See the analytics reports, if you have many such users then it's better to apply the patch.

Comment: ok. The solution works on my simple example, but not in my actual page... Will try to find how to edit the example to reproduce.

Comment: OK, if you can create a fiddle for that, that'd be nice. Although I don't have IE8, I'll try changing document mode.

Comment: Actually even my simple example does not work, for some reason IE had switched to IE7 compatibility mode by itself when I tested your solution. But with plain IE8 it still overlaps. It seems IE8 ignores `*display:inline` and uses `display:inline-block`, while IE7 does use `*display`. Note that I don't reproduce in IE9 with IE8 mode, I use a [modern.ie](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) VM. Anyway jsfiddle does not seems to work with IE8...